# Selecting a second array based on the first one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conditional-statements, subset

Let's say I have two arrays of **`len(1000)` each**

```
array_a = np.array([1,2,3,....,1000]) # length of 1000
array_b = np.array([32344,83242,94323,....,48984]) # length of 1000
```

Now I select a subset of `array_a` based on certain conditions:

```
subset_a = array_a[(array_a>10) * (array_a<500)]
```

Now how do I select those values of `array_b` that belong to the above `subset_a` ?

I tried

```
subset_b = array_b[subset_a]
```

but I get an error

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Comment: So, basically, you want to get some value pairs based on a selection of a value range of the first part. So let's say something like [(1,32344), (2,83242)]?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `pandas`?

Comment: If I can get the above, then yeah why not!

Comment: additional point: if you have base python lists, convert them to numopy array is possible or `array_b[[i for i in array_a if i>3 and i<6]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
import numpy as np

array_a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]) # length of 5
array_b = np.array([6,7,8,9,10]) # length of 5

condition = array_a>3
print condition
subset_a = array_a[condition]
print subset_a
subset_b = array_b[condition]
print subset_b
```

http://ideone.com/dAFLYL

Comment: but in this case `subset_a` becomes boolean right? I want to use both `subset_a` and `subset_b` for plotting.. SO I want them to be numbers. Is there any other way of doing this without calling `subset_a` twice? i.e. once as a boolean and secondly as an array with condition?